# How to find a value that doesn't exist in one table through another table in SQL

Tags: sql-server

**Publisher Table**
[image: Publisher Table]

**Book Table**
[image: Book Table]

These are the 2 tables in my SQL query and I want to find out the publisher that has not published any book

I use the SQL Server and I used:

```
SELECT PublisherID 
FROM Publisher 
WHERE PublisherID NOT IN (SELECT PublisherID FROM Book);
```

but it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

This is the result for this query
**Result Table**

[image: Result Table]

Comment: I just get a blank table with only the column names

Comment: It's supposed to show PublisherID = P04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use condition `PublisherID IS NOT NULL` inside sub query. Your `NULL` record was returning `false` for all rows.

```
SELECT PublisherID 
FROM Publisher 
WHERE PublisherID NOT IN (SELECT PublisherID FROM Book WHERE PublisherID IS NOT NULL);
```

---

Alternativaly you can use `LEFT JOIN` and add a condition with `WHERE b.PublisherID IS NULL`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Publisher p
    LEFT JOIN Book b
        ON b.PublisherID = p.PublisherID
WHERE b.PublisherID IS NULL
```

---

To find out the publisher that has published more than 1 book you can use `GROUP BY` & `HAVING` with `IN` like below.

```
SELECT PublisherID 
FROM @Publisher 
WHERE PublisherID IN (
    SELECT PublisherID
    FROM @Book 
    WHERE PublisherID IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY PublisherID
    HAVING COUNT(PublisherID) > 1
);
```

Comment: How can I find out the publisher that has published more than 1 book

Comment: You can use `GROUP BY` & `HAVING` to find such result

Answer (score 0):

[**`NOT IN` can return incorrect results**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11074428/14868997) when `NULL` values are involved. Instead use a `NOT EXISTS`

```sql
SELECT p.PublisherID 
FROM Publisher p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Book b
    WHERE b.PublisherID = p.PublisherID
);
```